# How do I use alarm manager to stop an alarm at a certain time?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

in my app i have an alarm manager that sets phone to silent at a certain time how would i get it to set the phone back to loud after the user specified time is past?

Comment: Are you asking how to set the alarm, or how to set the volume? What method are you using to mute the phone? What method are you using to set the alarm for silent mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your silence-the-phone event occurs, schedule a new one with `AlarmManager`, in which you restore the volume.